# Combining 2D array with a 1D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays one is a `int[][] pixelYArray` and the other one is a `int[] pixelXArray`.  I can not set the full width and height of the image as lenghts because these pixels are already filtered on. For example having the color yellow and these are the left over pixels and I want to create an array or object like this:

```
 [
  {
    "pixel x" : 1,
    "pixel y" : [
      1, 2, 3, 100, 101, 102
    ]
  },{
    "pixel x" : 3,
    "pixel y" : [
      1, 2, 32, 100, 101, 102
    ]
  },
]
```

the text `"pixel x"` and `"pixel y"` are optional and not needed if its makes it easier to create the array. In Javascript you can achieve it by doing something like this

```
let array = [];
for(int i=0;i < pixelYArray.length;i++){
    let tmpArr = [];
    for(int j=0;j < pixelYArray[i].length; j++){
        tmpArr.push(pixelYArray[i][j]);
    }
    array.push({
        "pixel x" : pixelXArray[i],
        "pixel y" : tmpArr
    });
    /* or
    array.push({
        pixelXArray[i],
        tmpArr
    }); */
}
```

only how can you achieve this in Java because you can not create objects like this or push them into an array. I have a for loop like this:

```
   for(int i=0;i < pixelYArray.length;i++){
        System.out.println("pixel x: " + pixelXArray[i] + " pixel y: ");
        for(int j=0;j < pixelYArray[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(pixelYArray[i][j] + "\t" );
        }
        System.out.println("\nEnd of Pixels for row \n");
    }
```

what gives an result like this and many more layers of X pixels and y pixels ofc [image: rows of X and Y pixelsn as result of the loop]

Comment: you'd use lists instead, there you can add stuff dynamically. if you insist on arrays, you have to create a new one for each `push`, add the additional element and copy the content of the previous state. I did it [here](https://github.com/curiosag/redundant_csv_parser/blob/master/Parser.java) in the `prepend`methods, but its cumbersome.

Comment: Note that arrays in Java need to have their length defined when they are created so you might want to use a `List<List<Integer>>` instead (so a list of lists of integers). If you create a class, e.g. `FilteredLine`, that contains the list of pixels and that `"pixel x" value, it would become a `List<FilteredLine>` and `FilteredLine` would contain a `List<Ineger>`.

Comment: I actually both change them to arrays cuz there were list before so is it then better to make from those 2 sepperate list 1 list instead of converting and then trying to combine them?

Comment: I think its up to you, to decide what you find more annoying. I suppose you had your reasons to throw out the lists and use arrays instead.

Comment: Yes but, I feel like converting a list to array to a list is just bad practise is it not? is it then just not better to convert it to a list to combined list to array instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Color> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Color c = new Color();
        c.pixel_x = 1;
        c.pixel_y.add(1);
        c.pixel_y.add(2);
        c.pixel_y.add(3);
        c.pixel_y.add(100);
        c.pixel_y.add(101);
        c.pixel_y.add(102);

        list.add(c);

        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

```java
class Color {
    public int pixel_x;
    public List<Integer> pixel_y;

    public Color() {
        pixel_x = 0;
        pixel_y = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return pixel_x + " " + pixel_y;
    }
}
```

First you create a `Color` object that contains `pixel_x` of type `Integer` and `pixel_y` of type `List<Integer>` then in your main, every time you create a `Color` instance, add it to `List<Color>`.

Comment: It works but for every new X pixel u need to create a new color object right? is that not gonna be an performance issue if u have alot of X pixels and or images

Comment: in your case working with array in java can't be done because unlike javascript array length in java must be known on compiling , and the best solution is to use Collections like List